# Can anybody help me how to implement localization and mapping in ROS?

Tags: slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a new user of ROS. Before implementing SLAM on ROS, I want to go with either implementing mapping with known pose or localization with known map. Please help me how to start with.

...... Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211824/can-anybody-help-me-how-to-implement-localization-and-mapping-in-ros?/) by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2015-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, you got to take a look at [ROS navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation), the tutorials are very helpful.

For mapping with known pose, you can use gmapping package to handle that for you. But if you are using your own robot, you need to prepare the driver to bridge the robot hardware to ROS topics like /cmd_vel, /odom, etc.

As for localization with known map, amcl is the package you'll probably use.

BTW, please show what survey you did before instead of asking a vague question and looking forward to a detailed answer.

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2015-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

there are 3 diffrent commen typs of Stacks you can use

1. [Hector](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam)
2. [Karto](http://wiki.ros.org/nav2d)
3. [Gmapper](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) + [AMCL](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl)

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2015-06-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1